# Заполнение большого двумерного массива в C++

Tags: массивы, память, c++

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int mas[10000][10000];
    for (int a=0;a<10000;a++)
    {
        for (int b=0;b<10000;b++)
        {
            mas[a][b] = 5;
        }

    }
    cout << "Done";
    return 0;
}
```

Вылетает переполнение стека. Как его заполнить?

Answer (score 6):

Переполнение стека - потому что забиваете стек объемом в `10000*10000*4` байт, что весьма прилично. Что можно сделать?

- использовать динамическую память (кучу) или делать массив глобальным (тогда он будет не стеке)
- перейти на другую операционную систему и/или компилятор. Так в ДОСе с объемом памяти всегда швах, несмотря на то какой компилятор использовать :-)
- поиграть с опциями компоновщика. Это может позволить увеличить объем памяти, выделяемой под стек.

Вообще смотри еще:
[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program), [Codeforces](http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/4429), [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a5b32b6-683b-4729-92d3-45ed7a89ef3f/stack-overflow-and-how-to-increase-the-stack-size)

Comment: IMHO 400 MB однозначно надо динамически выделять.

Comment: @avp, а разве под глобальные переменные нельзя столько места выделить? кажется, но секция data в исполняемом файле достаточно "резиновая"
А вообще соглашусь - динамика в данном случае оптимальный вариант.

Comment: @gecube, никогда не проверял, но думаю что можно и в data.

Просто трудно представить программу, для которой выделение именно такого (определяемого на стадии компиляции, т.е. константного) размера памяти выглядит разумным.

Обычно мы узнаем, сколько памяти нужно выделить под рассчеты, уже после анализа входных данных.